# About National D visa withdraw

Tags: visa, germany, resident-permit, france, student-visa

I got national D visa for study in Gemany but now i want to go france for study where i have already got admission. Please help me out with this. Is it possible to withdraw and then apply to france.is it possible from my country to start processing again for france or better to go germany then apply from there for  france national - D visa. Thank you in advance.